# iOS App Rejection if Cordova.js file keep on server

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, app-store

Is anybody aware about iOS application rejection due to keep only Cordova.js file on server for the application?

If anybody had already experienced of that then let me know.

Please share your suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple guidelines says they will not approve apps which downloads any kind of code. So if you keep cordova.js file on the server, its a default candidate fro rejection. Even if apple allows it, keeping cordova.js in server is a bad idea as your app will take many seconds to boot, slowing down your app unnecessarily. Always bundle all the required code files inside the app package!

Comment: hmm.. Thanks for your reply.. What if I inject javascript content of Cordova.js file in webview. So it should not a deafult candidate for rejection :)